# modal and while loop

Tags: php, bootstrap-modal

I have been scratching my head about this for days and i cant seem to understand why this isnt working,

i have a modal which pops up when selecting the accept button, this modal should populate the users name and telephone number.

the problem is that when you select the accept it only populate the first persons details and no the rest of the people in the table, i dont understand why if anyone can point out why i would be much obliged

here is my code (sorry its abit messy at the moment):

```
<?php

require_once ("includes/session_check.php");

require_once ("includes/db_connect.php");

//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, phone, requester,goodorbad,confirmed,denied FROM request WHERE goodorbad=1 AND confirmed=0 AND denied=0 Order by ID ASC");
echo '
      <!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
      MAIN CONTENT
      *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
          <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Non Authenticated Requests</h3>
            <div class="row mt">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Non Authenticated Requests here.</p>';
echo '<div class="row mt">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="content-panel">
                          <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                              <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Non Authenticated Requests</h4>
                              <hr>  <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>Username</th>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone number update request</th>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>Requester</th>
                                  <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Status</th>
                                  <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Accept/Decline</th>
                                  <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>';


while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {

    //$row->id
   //$row->confirmed
     //$row->denied

$status = $row->confirmed;

echo ' 
    <!-- Modal for Confirm -->

                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal" class="modal fade">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                   <input type="hidden" name="username_request" value="'.$row->username.'"/>
                                       <input type="hidden" name="telephone_request" value="'.$row->phone.'"/>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure ?</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <br>

                                    <p>You are about to update </p>
                                    '.$row->username.'
                                    <br>
                                    <p> with the following telephone number </p>
                                      '.$row->phone.'

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" 
                                            type="button">Cancel</button>
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" 
                                            type="button">Submit</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- modal -->




                              <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td><a href="#">'.$row->username.'</a></td>
                                  <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
                                  <td>'.$row->requester.' </td>';
        if($status == 1){


              echo '       <td><span class="label label-success">Completed</span></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      ';
        }else{

        }

                            echo '<td><span class="label label-info label-mini">Pending</span></td>

                                  <td>
                                    Accept?  
                                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal"> <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                                     </a>
                                   <td>
                                   Decline?
                                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                                     </td>
                                  </td>


                            </tr>
                              </tbody>





                      ';
}

echo '     
                          </table>
                      </div><!-- /content-panel -->
                  </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
              </div><!-- /row -->';

// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>

<html>


</html>
```

Comment: you should add a unique key in the model . otherwise it will catch the first element found .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add unique `id` to every `model`.

Try

```
<?php

require_once ("includes/session_check.php");

require_once ("includes/db_connect.php");

//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, phone, requester,goodorbad,confirmed,denied FROM request WHERE goodorbad=1 AND confirmed=0 AND denied=0 Order by ID ASC");
echo '
      <!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
      MAIN CONTENT
      *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
          <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Non Authenticated Requests</h3>
            <div class="row mt">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Non Authenticated Requests here.</p>';
echo '<div class="row mt">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="content-panel">
                          <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                              <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Non Authenticated Requests</h4>
                              <hr>  <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>Username</th>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone number update request</th>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>Requester</th>
                                  <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Status</th>
                                  <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Accept/Decline</th>
                                  <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>';

$i = 1;
while($row = $results->fetch_object())
{

    //$row->id
   //$row->confirmed
     //$row->denied

$status = $row->confirmed;

echo ' 
    <!-- Modal for Confirm -->

                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal'.$i.'" class="modal fade">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                   <input type="hidden" name="username_request" value="'.$row->username.'"/>
                                       <input type="hidden" name="telephone_request" value="'.$row->phone.'"/>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure ?</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <br>

                                    <p>You are about to update </p>
                                    '.$row->username.'
                                    <br>
                                    <p> with the following telephone number </p>
                                      '.$row->phone.'

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" 
                                            type="button">Cancel</button>
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" 
                                            type="button">Submit</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- modal -->




                              <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td><a href="#">'.$row->username.'</a></td>
                                  <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
                                  <td>'.$row->requester.' </td>';
        if($status == 1)
        {


              echo '       <td><span class="label label-success">Completed</span></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      ';
        }

                            echo '<td><span class="label label-info label-mini">Pending</span></td>

                                  <td>
                                    Accept?  
                                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal'.$i.'"> <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                                     </a>
                                   <td>
                                   Decline?
                                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                                     </td>
                                  </td>


                            </tr>
                              </tbody>
';
$i++;
}

echo '     
                          </table>
                      </div><!-- /content-panel -->
                  </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
              </div><!-- /row -->';

// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>

<html>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to solve my problem, but i dont understand why each model needs a ID, if you dont mind could you explain to me why?

Comment: @user3165482 Model structure needs unique `id` to make relationship between `<button>` and `model`.

Comment: @user3165482 please vote up my answer. If you found it useful.

Comment: @user3165482, for your clear understanding, i am going to brief in short. When you will use only one modal as popup, then it will be good and popup will not make problem. But if you make a table fetching data from database to show a list and in every row you use a popup command, then you will have to use a unique modal name, so that compiler understands in which modal you are using which data. I hope this is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change 2 lines. The reason of error is you are calling the same id again and again. So you will have to change id dynamically with loop. You will have to change your 2 lines like these:

```
<div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal'.$i.'" class="modal fade">
```

and

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal'.$i.'"> <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button></a>
```

Final code is:

```
<?php

require_once ("includes/session_check.php");

require_once ("includes/db_connect.php");

//MySqli Select Query
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, username, phone, requester,goodorbad,confirmed,denied FROM request WHERE goodorbad=1 AND confirmed=0 AND denied=0 Order by ID ASC");
echo '
      <!-- **********************************************************************************************************************************************************
      MAIN CONTENT
      *********************************************************************************************************************************************************** -->
      <!--main content start-->
      <section id="main-content">
          <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
            <h3><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Non Authenticated Requests</h3>
            <div class="row mt">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                <p>Non Authenticated Requests here.</p>';
echo '<div class="row mt">
                  <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="content-panel">
                          <table class="table table-striped table-advance table-hover">
                              <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>Non Authenticated Requests</h4>
                              <hr>  <thead>
                              <tr>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i>Username</th>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>Phone number update request</th>
                                  <th><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i>Requester</th>
                                  <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Status</th>
                                  <th><i class=" fa fa-edit"></i> Accept/Decline</th>
                                  <th></th>
                              </tr>
                              </thead>';

$i=0;
while($row = $results->fetch_object()) {
$i++;
    //$row->id
   //$row->confirmed
     //$row->denied

$status = $row->confirmed;

echo ' 
    <!-- Modal for Confirm -->

                <form action="#" method="POST">
                    <div aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" id="myModal'.$i.'" class="modal fade">
                        <div class="modal-dialog">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                   <input type="hidden" name="username_request" value="'.$row->username.'"/>
                                       <input type="hidden" name="telephone_request" value="'.$row->phone.'"/>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title">Are you sure ?</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <br>

                                    <p>You are about to update </p>
                                    '.$row->username.'
                                    <br>
                                    <p> with the following telephone number </p>
                                      '.$row->phone.'

                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" 
                                            type="button">Cancel</button>
                                    <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default" 
                                            type="button">Submit</button>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <!-- modal -->




                              <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                  <td><a href="#">'.$row->username.'</a></td>
                                  <td>'.$row->phone.'</td>
                                  <td>'.$row->requester.' </td>';
        if($status == 1){


              echo '       <td><span class="label label-success">Completed</span></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                      ';
        }else{

        }

                            echo '<td><span class="label label-info label-mini">Pending</span></td>

                                  <td>
                                    Accept?  
                                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal'.$i.'"> <button class="btn btn-success btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
                                     </a>
                                   <td>
                                   Decline?
                                      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button>
                                     </td>
                                  </td>


                            </tr>
                              </tbody>





                      ';
}

echo '     
                          </table>
                      </div><!-- /content-panel -->
                  </div><!-- /col-md-12 -->
              </div><!-- /row -->';

// close connection 
$mysqli->close();
?>

<html>


</html>
```

Comment: I already posted answer/solution 10 mints ago and it works for OP. What is new in your answer?

Comment: Probably, the time you answered, i was making my solutions. I now see that you already gave answer. I hope you understand.